# can the ios collectionview contain albums of albums?

Tags: ios, ipad, uicollectionview

Before setting sail on my voyage of discovery, I'm wondering if my destination is reachable.  Can the iOS uiCollectionview be made up of albums, containing albums of albums?

Is using the CollectionView the brightest idea for navigating something 4-5 levels deep?  This is for the iPad so I steered away from a TableView taking up the entire screen width.

Thank you for any guidance in advance!

Comment: UICollectionView is interface (view). "Albums" is some kind of underlying notion (model). View can't be "made up" of model. If you have a model ("albums of albums", whatever that means), then coming up with a way to represent it visually is up to you. There is nothing about UICollectionView, or any other built-in widget, that makes it more or less suitable for this; you have to plan how you want this visual representation to look, and then implement it.

Comment: if you mean you want `UICollectionView` inside each `UICollectionViewCell` of a 'super-collectionview', then yes it's possible

Comment: yes, a box of boxes.  A UICollectionView's UICollectionViewCell containing another UICollectionView would work.